# Test runs fine in postman but fails in newman. I am running tests after connecting to VPN as 2 APIs among 47 only work once connected to VPN

Tags: postman, newman

Connected to VPN: Postman runner works fine and shows results but when I execute the same by Newman it throws error.

Disconnect VPN: Newman runner now works fine with same command and collection but this time those 2 APIs which require VPN fails.

How can i solve this network issue causing newman to fail.

Error newman throws is

```
[errored]
     connect ECONNREFUSED ipaddress:443
 11⠄ JSONError in test-script
```

Comment: Would adding the `-k` flag to the end of the Newman command do anything?

Comment: Yes tried with -k flag but still got the same error.

Comment: What i believe here is newman downloads the dependencies every time we execute it and as it download from internet the VPN is blocking that. I have to find solution for newman downloading node from npm via internet to download it from some local repo which is allowed by vpn

Comment: How are you running this? Are you destroying the environment after the run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to setup HTTP proxy before giving the Newman run command and it worked.

HTTP_PROXY='Give URL:PORT NUMBER' newman run file.json